# ZF2 Zend\Console routes don't match in windows command prompt

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have set up a couple of console routes in a Zend Framework 2 project to test out, and while it works on linux (ubuntu 12.10) , it won't work on my windows 7 machine using command prompt or cygwin. I just get the following error message:

> Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided

In my module.config.php file, I have

```
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'some-route' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'some route',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Application\Controller\Cron',
                        'action'        => 'some-route'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'another-route' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'another route',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Application\Controller\Cron',
                        'action'        => 'another-route'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And in my controller

```
class CronController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function someRouteAction()
    {
        return 'some route called' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function anotherRouteAction()
    {
        return 'some other route called' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a reason why the exact same code works on ubuntu but not on windows?

Answer (score 0):

1- You can check the router factory on Zend/Mvc/Service/RouterFactory.php  to make sure that your console routing configuration is not in cache.

```
public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $cName = null, $rName = null)
{
$config = $serviceLocator->get('Configuration') ;

//@ToDo Remove
print_r($config);  

if(
     $rName === 'ConsoleRouter' ||
      ($cName === 'router' && Console::isConsole())
) {
    if(isset($config['console']) && isset($config['console']['router'])){
        $routerConfig = $config['console']['router'] ;
    } else {
        $routerConfig = array();
    }
    $router = ConsoleRouter::factory($routerConfig) ;
} else {
    [&#8230;]
}
return $router ;
}
```

2. Alternatively it is necessary to verify in application.config.php if config_cache_enabled is true